# C# replace string except when preceded by another

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I want to replace all ocurrence of `"` by `\"` in a string except if this `"` is preceded by a `\`
for exemple the string `hello "World\"` will become `hello \"World\"`

Is it possible without using regex ?
But if I have to use regex, what kind have I to use ?

Thanks for help,
regards,

Comment: Side note: If this is about character escaping, then beware of edge cases in your scenario, like dealing with source strings in the form `"World\\"`. A simple look-behind regex might not be the answer. This edge case can be recursively expanded into: What to do when source string is `"World\\\"`? What to do when string is `"World\\\\"`? etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a lookbehind:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\\)""", @"\""")
```

Or you could just make the preceeding character optional, for example:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\\?""", @"\""")
```

This works because `"` is replaced with `\"` (which is what you wanted), and `\"` is replaced with `\"`, so no change.

Answer (score 3):

The regex for this would be:

```
(?<!\\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a regex this should do:

```
yourStringVar.Replace("""","\\""").Replace("\\\\""","\\""");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without using regex:

```
  str = str.Replace(" \"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked if it's possible without using regex explicitly, that's not as simple and impossible with pure `String.Replace` approaches. You could use a loop and a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
builder.Append(text[0] == '"' ? "\\\"" : text.Substring(0, 1));
for (int i = 1; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    Char next = text[i];
    Char last = text[i - 1];
    if (next == '"' && last != '\\')
        builder.Append("\\\"");
    else
       builder.Append(next);
}
string result = builder.ToString();
```

Edit: here's a demo (difficult to create that string literal): http://ideone.com/Xmeh1w